# I need help setting up my printer

Tags: printing

I am trying to print to an HP deskjet 2510 series connected to my time capsule.

I'm running 13.10 on my macbook pro. I added the printer and it says it is connected, but when I try to print anything it just sits in the queue processing.

Any tips here knowing that the printer works fine when I am using osx.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are the HPLIP Drivers For Ubuntu. http://hplipopensource.com/hplip-web/install.html

Simply Install Them And Your Printer should work just fine. it worked for me so if you have any questions, Ask!
Enjoy!!!!

Answer (score 0):

What you have to do, after installing HPLIP, is to go to the Printers tab (in System Tools) and mark your printer as Default Printer (right click at the printer icon). Also make sure that it's enabled (right click at the printer icon). After you do so, your printer will be ready to print.